# Conditionally adding a line to text box with bulleted list in SSRS

Tags: html, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm a competent C# developer, but new to SSRS, so my inability to figure out this stupid little issue is kinda killing me here.

I've got a report that's basically a printed quote. There's a terms and conditions section at the bottom that looks like

some static text

some static text

some static text

With certain quote types, we want to add one more line to the bottom of that. I've tried a bunch of ways to get this to work, but can't seem to get it to work within the bulleted list. If I add a new line with the bullet, I've got a blank bullet when the quote type doesn't call for that item. If I clear the bullet and try to manually add it with chr(9) for tabs, it doesn't work. The closest I could get to it was this:

> =iif(Trim(First(Fields!QuoteTypeCode.Value, "QuoteDetailsDataSet")) = "N", "      •      Prices Subject to Change", "")

Problem is, that still leaves an unwanted blank line. Ideally, I'd think my solution would be to put my «expr» at the end of the last static text line and trigger a line break that would add another bullet and my text, or, after that line, with html, add a <li>my text</li>, but none of that works.

Is there something silly that I'm missing here?

I could easily just create two versions of this box, one with that line, one without, and conditionally display the appropriate one, depending on what type of quote it is, but that feels "dirty". At this point though, as simple as this task is, I'm ready to go dirty rather than spin my wheels for too much longer over something so trivial. :(

Comment: Have you tried "vbcrlf" to add the new line character with the expression you mention above?

Answer (score 0):

I would Create a separate dataset, ex. Italicsdataset

```
select  "bullet text formatted in html" as Option1, "bullet option 2" as Option  2...
```

then in your text box select create an expression such as

```
IIF(fields!Field.value = 1, fields!option1.value, 0)
```